# Having issues with Training Loss during neural network training

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, training-data

`I am currently working on a dataset to build a DeepONet architecture neural network model using a simple Tensorflow library. During the training, I observed that my training loss is highly unstable and is not decreasing no matter what I try with different learning rates, modifying the architecture layers, batch size, epochs, etc.  I tried modifying the architecture with different sizes, learning rates, loss functions, batch sizes, epochs, etc. but haven't had any success so far in achieving stable loss over the epochs. What I am observing is that the training loss is not decreasing, it's oscillating. I have normalised the data before feeding to the architecture.
**Please note that I am new to implementing DeepLearning models.**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import pandas as pd


class FNN(tf.keras.Model):
    
    def __init__(selfT):
        super().__init__()

        pass

    def hyper_initial(self, layers):
        L = len(layers)
        W = []
        b = []
        for l in range(1, L):
            in_dim = layers[l - 1]
            out_dim = layers[l]
            std = np.sqrt(2. / (in_dim + out_dim))
            weight = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(shape=[in_dim, out_dim], stddev=std))
            bias = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[1, out_dim]))
            W.append(weight)
            b.append(bias)

        return W, b

    def fnn_T(self, W, b, X, Xmin, Xmax):
        A = 2.0 * (X - Xmin) / (Xmax - Xmin) - 1.0
        L = len(W)
        for i in range(L - 1):
            A = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(A, W[i]), b[i]))

        Y = tf.add(tf.matmul(A, W[-1]), b[-1])

        return Y

    def fnn_B(self, W, b, X, Xmin, Xmax):
        A = 2.0 * (X - Xmin) / (Xmax - Xmin) - 1.0  # Normalization similar to fnn_T
        L = len(W)
        for i in range(L - 1):
            A = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(A, W[i]), b[i]))

        Y = tf.add(tf.matmul(A, W[-1]), b[-1])

        return Y

#output dimension of Branch/Trunk
p = 100
num = 1
#branch net
layer_B = [num, 64, 128, 256, 512, p]
#trunk net
layer_T = [1, 64, 128, 256, 512, 512, p]
#batch_size
bs = 256
epochs = 10


fnn_model = FNN()
num_actual_values = actual_time_points.shape[0]

input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1009,1))  # Define the appropriate shape
input2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1009,1))  # Define the appropriate shape

concatenated_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([input1, input2])
dense_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(concatenated_inputs)
dense_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(dense_1)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(dense_2)

mu_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=output)

mu_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
fnn_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)

mu_model.compile(optimizer=mu_optimizer, loss='mean_squared_error')

DON_train_losses = []

for epoch in range(epochs):
    epoch_loss = 0.0
    for i in range(0, len(pH_data), bs):
        pH_batch = pH_data[i:i + bs]
        time_batch = time_points[i:i + bs]

        with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
           
            W_B, b_B = fnn_model.hyper_initial(layer_B)

            W_T, b_T = fnn_model.hyper_initial(layer_T)         

            u_B = fnn_model.fnn_B(W_B, b_B, pH_data, min(pH_data), max(pH_data))
            u_T = fnn_model.fnn_T(W_T, b_T, final_random_time_points, min(final_random_time_points),
                                  max(final_random_time_points))

            # Convert NumPy arrays to TensorFlow tensors
            u_B = tf.convert_to_tensor(u_B)
            u_T = tf.convert_to_tensor(u_T)

            
            u_nn = tf.matmul(u_B, u_T)

           

            u_pred = tf.reduce_sum(u_nn, axis=-1, keepdims=True)

         

            selected_u_pred = tf.gather(u_pred, selected_VCD_indices)

           

            # Compute dvcd_dt using TensorFlow's gradient computation
            with tf.GradientTape() as grad_tape:
                time_points_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(scaled_time_points)
                grad_tape.watch(time_points_tf)
                u_pred_at_time = tf.reduce_sum(u_nn, axis=-1)


            dvcd_dt_data = grad_tape.gradient(u_pred_at_time, time_points_tf)

           
            if dvcd_dt_data is None or tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(dvcd_dt_data, 0)):
                
                dvcd_dt_data = tf.random.normal(tf.shape(time_points_tf), stddev=1e-5)

                       
           
            mu_data = tf.divide(dvcd_dt_data, u_pred)

           
            mu_pred = mu_model([scaled_pH_data, u_pred])
            mu_pred = tf.reshape(mu_pred, (-1, 1))

           

            

            # Compute losses
            operator_loss_value = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(scaled_selected_vcd_data - selected_u_pred))
            physics_loss_value = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(dvcd_dt_data - mu_pred * u_pred))
            total_loss = operator_loss_value + 0.3 * physics_loss_value

        
        mu_gradients = tape.gradient(total_loss, mu_model.trainable_variables)
      

        # Compute gradients for fnn_model
        fnn_gradients = tape.gradient(total_loss, fnn_model.trainable_variables)

        

        mu_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(mu_gradients, mu_model.trainable_variables))
        #
        fnn_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(fnn_gradients, fnn_model.trainable_variables))

        epoch_loss += total_loss.numpy()

    epoch_loss /= (len(pH_data) / bs)

    DON_train_losses.append(epoch_loss)

    

    if epoch % 100 == 0:
        print(f"Epoch {epoch}: Train Loss: {epoch_loss}")


print(f"Epoch {epochs - 1}: Train Loss: {epoch_loss}")

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.plot(range(epochs), DON_train_losses, label='Training Loss', color='blue')
plt.title('Training Loss over Epochs')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Training Loss')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```